# Simplest, smallest antenna for tuning WWV, WWVH?

Tags: receiver, testing, calibration

I'd like to perform some simple receiver testing and calibration (mostly for frequency variance, not signal strength) and [have been told WWV/WWVH transmissions can be found throughout most of the US](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1232).

What would be a good, cheap, small antenna for receiving one or more of these transmissions at 2.5MHz, 5MHz, 10MHz, 15MHz, and 20MHz? I note that it's common for "atomic" clocks to have such an antenna internal, and if I find one lying about I'll use it, but I don't keep such clocks, nevermind random ferrite rods, lying about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a simple, diy, antenna suitable of HF receive only?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/is-there-a-simple-diy-antenna-suitable-of-hf-receive-only)

Comment: That question doesn't really approach the request for small antenna design that this one asks for.

Comment: How is it different? An antenna for WWV isn't different than any other HF antenna for a similar frequency. This question is also unanswerable. The "smallest" antenna might be a 1mm long wire. In some locations (right next to the transmitter), this is entirely sufficient to receive the signal. But, that's probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: I'm going to assume you are in the USA. Here in Australia, the signals are somewhat harder to catch (I believe they come from Hawaii). What works for you in size & simplicity probably won't work for me. Considering that, take any advice you get with a grain of salt until it's assembled, connected and verified by your own eyes & ears.

Comment: Note that atomic clocks typically receive signals from [WWVB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWVB) which, while broadcast from essentially the same site as WWV, is a rather different signal: the rods in those radios would be tuned to 60kHz, yes *kilo*hertz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your receiver sensitivity and antenna location. I've seen some many-decades-old portable shortwave radios pick up at least one WWV frequency using their simple built-in half-meter to meter long metal whip antenna.

Answer (score 1):

An end-fed http://www.aa5tb.com/efha.html tuned for 2.5MHz will also serve well at the higher frequencies you seek.

Comment: Why is an end-fed antenna more suited to this application than any other?