# Swan 350 calibration

Tags: hf, transceiver, calibration, vfo

So my swan 350 needs to sing properly and order it for to do so the VFO needs to be calibrated. I do not have a working frequency counter.

How do I get this stuff fixed so I can get her singing right.

Is their a way to get the VFO calibrated without the use of a a frequency counter.

Comment: The 10m "tuning lugs" problem should probably be asked in a separate, new question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is their a way to get the vfo calibrated without the use of a a frequency counter?

There certainly is! We use the US and Canadian government's standard frequency radio stations. See this question and answers:

[Are there any good, consistently receivable signals in the US for HF receiver testing?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/are-there-any-good-consistently-receivable-signals-in-the-us-for-hf-receiver-te)

No frequency counter needed!